# Extracting text from Java applets in bulk

Tags: java, html, applet

I am rebuilding [this database concepts application](http://adbc.kennesaw.edu) from the ground up. One of the many objectives is to remove all use of Flash and Java.

The application has tens of Java applets that all need to be rebuilt as HTML forms. In each applet, you can find text, tables and other content that will eventually end up with a corresponding HTML representation. An example applet is shown below.

[image: Example applet content]

I have access to the applet source, but I did not write it, nor do I want to dig through each one and manually copy content. **Is it possible to automatically extract any (or all) of the clear text, table data, and other content from the applets, and if so, how?**

**NOTE:** Oddly enough, the entire web application has NO database. All relevant content can be found in files.

Comment: Isn't that table data backed by a database table? If so, you can pull it from database right

Comment: Nope. The entire application has no database. Glad you brought it up. Editing question.

Comment: If i understand correctly you want to extract the html fragments from files? If so then write a html text parser

Comment: No, the content I want is in a series of Java applet files. I just intend to put them in HTML forms.

Comment: One way to get access to the fields and attributes of an applet is to extend it.  Another way is to write a trusted applet to wrap the other applets and inspect their attributes using reflection.  I'm not sure either of those would be less work than copy/pasting the values from the existing applets though, and those approaches will only really work with static data - that data appears to be very dynamic.  As an aside, it really looks like the applet(s) are teaching SQL, so I'd be tempted to replace all that with a DB on the server side for all the JS/HTML based interface to work with.